# What storage engine does wordpress 3.6 use?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The older versions of wordpress seem to use MyISAM as default storage engine with MYSQL. But with InnoDB 5.6 fulltext search is available. Is wordpress still using MyISAM or any other storage engine (or a combination) now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know [this answer on Wordpress' support pages is still valid](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-use-innodb-by-default);

> By default, WordPress uses the database's default database type. WordPress doesn't pick a type, in other words. It just takes what it gets.

As from MySQL 5.5.5, the default storage engine is InnoDB, but [you can change it in my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html) or alter your tables after the fact. If you need full text search to work in InnoDB, you'll need MySQL 5.6 or later.

Comment: For anyone who's next question will be: _So, which engine do I actually use?_, continue to [how-to-know-storage-engine-used](https://serverfault.com/q/244755)